# $location.path do Angular mudou?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Bom dia pessoal!

Estou tentando fazer uma function com $location.path('/main'); e quandochamoa função, a seguinte mensagem aparece no console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Por que isso?

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $location) {

    $scope.fazerLogin = function(usuario){
        /*$http.post("", usuario).success(function(data){

        });*/
    $location.path('/main');
}


}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua primeira linha com a declaração do `controller` está incompleta. O correto seria:

```
...
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $location) {
...
```

Agora um ponto de melhoria. Se você utilizar [Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#named-vs-anonymous-functions) (que é um material muito interessante que aumenta muito o código escrito), você deve declarar o `controller` da seguinte forma:

```
...
.controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

LoginCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location'];

function LoginCtrl($scope, $stateParams, $http, $location) {
...
```

Comment: Blz, funcionou.
Mas por que tenho que colocar ['$http', '$location', function... tb? Mudançca recente?

Comment: Não é mudança, você tem que declarar todas as propriedades que você vai usar, senão fica sem referência, e por isso deu `undefined`

Comment: Mas em outra aplicação que tenho, eu não fazia dessa forma e e funciona!!

Comment: @GustavoSevero provavelmente você não declarava nenhuma, aí funciona. Esse modo de declarar como `string` serve pra quando você vai minificar o arquivo. Aqui tem uma explicação na documentação [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). Se você quiser pode abrir outra pergunta pedindo pro pessoal te explicar em detalhes